# How to pick up JSON in PHP from Jeditable Script

Tags: php, json, jquery-plugins, jquery, jeditable

I want to create a jeditable text area that posts the values entered in to a database and then returns the new value to the div that replaces the textarea. I found this on Stackoverflow that handles returning the new value to the div.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

     $('.edit_area').editable(submitEdit, { 
            indicator : "Saving...",
            tooltip   : "Click to edit...",
            type : "textarea",
            submit : "OK",
            cancel : "Cancel",
                        name : "Editable.FieldName",
            id   : "elementid",


});
function submitEdit(value, settings)
{ 
   var edits = new Object();
   var origvalue = this.revert;
   var textbox = this;
   var result = value;
   edits[settings.name] = [value];
   var returned = $.ajax({
           url: "http://jimmymorris.co.uk/xmas/record_xmas_msg.php", 
           type: "POST",
           data : edits,
           dataType : "json",
           complete : function (xhr, textStatus) 
           {
               var response =  $.secureEvalJSON(xhr.responseText);
               if (response.Message != "") 
               {
                   alert(Message);
               } 
           }
           });
   return(result);
 }



 });
```

My problems is I don't know what my POST vars are called so I can insert in to my db. Does it even return POST var to php or does it send php json and how do I know what that is called?

Please help, Cheers in advance.

Comment: var_dump($_POST) in your PHP script.. Simple :)

Comment: Problem is I never see my PHP script because it's called in the background

Comment: Install firebug you can then open on the Net tab where you can see communication with the server (ajax requests and responses).

Answer (score 0):

What it sends to the server depends on what you supply to the "post" mamber of the $.ajax options paremeter. 
If you pass a query string parementer `data : "name=foo&surname=bar"` The PHP script would recieve it in the $_POST variable and could be accessed by means of `$_POST['name']` `$_POST['surname']` 
However if you passed an object to the data parameter it would be changed to a query string i.e

```
data : {name : 'foo', surname : 'bar'},
```

JQuery.ajax would change it into a query string like the example above then It would be sent to the server, and the PHP script would also access it same as mentioned above.

P.S I highly recommend using some type of encoding when sending data to the server, `encodeURIComponent(variable)` and accordingly decode it in PHP by using urldecode.

Answer (score 0):

You have the id posted which you can retrieve in the PHP page as `$_POST['id']`. The text is posted as value which you can retrieve in the PHP page as `$_POST['value']`. You can of course change the default names.